# How to prevent Vim adding a newline at EOF for LaTex files?

Tags: vim, tex

When I edit a LaTex (.tex) file Vim automatically adds a newline at the end of file on write. How do I disable this behavior (just for .tex files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be (almost) enough:

```
augroup mytex | au!
    autocmd FileType tex setlocal nofixeol
augroup end
```

But note that if some file already had a newline at the end, then that newline becomes "invisible" in Vim and you cannot remove it normally.

To deal with this you can use `setl eol?` and `setl noeol` manually, or simply add `setl noeol` to the autocommand.

See also embedded help system topics `:h eol` and `:h fixeol`.

Comment: Thanks, `nofixeol` seems useful. I wonder if it's a good or bad practice to have .tex files not ending with a newline (I need to edit some existing files, but I'm just curious).

Comment: @planetp TeX files always end upon encountering the command `\end` (or some macro invoking `\end`, such as `\bye`, `\end{document}` etc.) Thus it's purely stylistic issue.

Comment: @planetp all that said, some posix tools may expect to find a newline at the end of the last line